# Unable to set session in Firebase Hosting App (ExpressJs)

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, passport.js, firebase-hosting

In firebase hosting (localhost) I can't able to set session as

```
req.session.user = '123344';
```

on console `console.log(req.session)`   `//undefined`

I don't know the issue why firebase hosting not able to set session for express

Comment: Are you sure that you're referring to Firebase hosting? Because Firebase hosting is for serving static files like JS, CSS, images, HTML etc. It doesn't handle express or node js

Comment: dude have a look `https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions`

Comment: oops! I didn't know that. Thanks for the info